# can I dualboot kali and OSMC?

Tags: osmc, kali, multiboot

I have RPi 3 currently running the latest distro of kali, but I also want OSMC (or alternative) I can use NOOBS because they have a few OS's but not kali, same goes for berryboot is there any way I can custom dualboot both these OS's?

Comment: Wouldn't a second SD card be easier?

Comment: theoretically, yes but I have only 1 micro SD